# Variable Session JSP Java Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, session

buen dia tengo un problema creo una variable session para almacenar el usuario y clave de la persona que utilizara el sistema, pero al pasar los 30 minutos esta variable pasa ha ser "null"
lo que quiero lograr es que al ser session  = null que me redirija al Login pero no lo logro

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
session.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
            session.setAttribute("clave", clave);

String usuario = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("usuario"));
                   
                   if(usuario == null){
                       response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp"); 
                       
                   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si `session.getAttribute("usuario")` es `null`, el valor que resulta de hacer `String.valueOf(null)` es `"null"`, no `null`

Tu código debería ser:

```
String usuario = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("usuario"));
                   
                   if("null".equals(usuario)){
                       response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp"); 
                       
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de hacer la validación debes de mirar que el atributo sea null o vacío.

Esto...

```
  String usuario = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("usuario"));
                       
                       if(usuario == null){
                           response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp"); 
                           
                       }
```

Reemplazalo por esto..

```
if(null==session.getAttribute("usuario") || "".equals(session.getAttribute("usuario"))){
                           response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp"); 
}
```

si no te funciona con lo anterior, puedes echar un vistazo a la [pagina](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/java-servlet/session-timeout-and-forward-to-login.html).

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta he probado lo que me has indicado, desgraciadamente no me ha funcionado